# A counter-example for complex function limits using polar coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Can anybody give an example of a complex function $f(z)$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{z\longrightarrow 0}f(z)$ exists as a (finite) complex number, however, if we use the polar coordinates $[r, \theta]$ in the same limit, then $\displaystyle \lim_{r\longrightarrow 0}f(re^{i\theta})$ depends on $\theta$? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Nobody can give such an example because it doesn't exist.

Comment: So the existence of the limit $\lim_{z\longrightarrow 0} f(z)$ is equivalent to the existence of $\lim_{r\longrightarrow 0} f(re^{i\theta})$, isn't it?

Comment: If the limit exists when $z\rightarrow 0$, then it must exist and be the same for all directions in which $z$ approaches zero, and therefore, it is the same for all directions $\theta$ when using polar coordinates.

Comment: @serenus No, it is not equivalent. The existence of $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$ is **stronger**.

Comment: Opps, I see, there must be a counterexample in the opposite direction!

Comment: @serenus Exactly.

Comment: Hence I understand that if the limit $\lim_{r\longrightarrow 0}f(re^{i\theta})$ depends on theta, then we can conclude that the limit $\lim_{z\longrightarrow 0} f(z)$ does not exist. Is that okay?

Comment: Even stronger counterexamples exist: the limit when $r\to0$ may exist for every $\theta$ and its value be independent of $\theta$ and yet, the limit when $z\to0$ may not exist.

Comment: Could you please write an example with the properties you stated?

Comment: @Did: I mean; could you give a concrete example of a function $f(z)$
 such that, as you said, the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{r⟶0}f(re^{iθ})$
 exists for every $θ$ and its value independet of $θ$, but the limit $\displaystyle \lim_{z⟶0}f(z)$ does not exist ?

Comment: Consider $f(x+ix^2)=1$ for every $x$, $f(x+iy)=0$ for every $y\ne x^2$.

Comment: @Did: For this example  $\displaystyle \lim_{r⟶0} f(re^{iθ})=1$, isn't it?

Comment: Not at all. The limit at 0 along every fixed direction is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an example does not exist. In fact, what is true is:

> If $f$ is a complex function defined on a neighborhood of $0$ and $$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$$ exists and is equal to $L$, then the limit $$\lim_{r\to 0^+}f(re^{i\theta})$$ also exists and is equal to $L$.

Let's prove it using $\epsilon-\delta$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$, and let $\theta$ be any real number. Then, there exists some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|z-0|<\delta$, then $|f(z)-L|<\epsilon$ (by the definition of a limit).

Let $0<r<\delta$ be a real number and let $z_r=e^{i\theta}r$. Then, clearly, $|z_r|=r<\delta$, meaning (from the property written above) that we know that $|f(z_r)-L|<\epsilon$. But from the definition of $z_r$, this means $|f(re^{i\theta}) - L| < \epsilon$.

Therefore, $$\lim_{r\to o^+} f(re^{i\theta}) = L.$$